# Use a variable value in element description

Tags: java, selenium, qaf

Can i use variable value in the element description?

For Example , I have a variable "UserId" and I want its value to be included in the element description which gives a detailed view in the QAF report.

Is this possible in QAF , any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter in locator and then you need to set property before you create element object. For example:

**Locator**:

```
user.name.txtbox={'locator':'css=#userName';'desc':'User name for ${userID}'}
```

**Java**:

```
getBundle().setProperty("userID","u12345");
$("user.name.txtbox").sendKeys("Test User");
```

Example with page:

```
getBundle().setProperty("userID","u12345");
UserPage userPage = new UserPage();
userPage.getUserName().sendKeys("Test User");
```

** BDD**:

```
Given store "u12345" into "userID"
Then send Keys "Test User" into "user.name.txtbox"
```

If userId is same for entire execution, instead of setting through code you can set it [using one of the way to set property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html).